# Combine multiple columns into one column in the same dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
Time (min)   20m Wind Speed (m/s)    Wind Dir (deg)     40m Wind Speed (m/s)     Wind Dir (deg).1   60m Wind Speed (m/s)    60m Wind Dir (deg)
       1.0            1.5                     120.4                      2.5                133.2                   3.5                    190.5
```

I would like to combine all of the Wind Dir columns into a single Wind Dir (deg) column as well as all of the Wind Speed columns into a single Wind Speed (m/s) column so that the dataframe will look like the following:

```
Time (min)       Wind Speed (m/s)         Wind Dir (deg)                                                                                                                                                           
       1.0                    1.5                  120.4                    
       NAN                    2.5                  133.2
       NAN                    3.5                  190.5
```

I've looked into merge, join, and concatenate but these appear to be for combining different data frames together. I thought that maybe pd.melt or append might work but I don't think I'm implementing it correctly using the examples I had. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just copied and pasted your first code block and saved it as test.ssv.  You were on the right track with pd.melt.

```
# Python 2.7.12 and pandas 0.19.2
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/test.ssv', sep='\s\s+')

wind_speed_df = pd.melt(
    df, value_vars=['20m Wind Speed (m/s)', '40m Wind Speed (m/s)', '60m Wind Speed (m/s)'])
wind_dir_df = pd.melt(
    df, value_vars=['Wind Dir (deg)', 'Wind Dir (deg).1', '60m Wind Dir (deg)'])
wind_speed_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
wind_dir_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
wind_dir_df = wind_dir_df.rename(columns={'value': 'Wind Speed (m/s)'})
wind_speed_df = wind_speed_df.rename(columns={'value': 'Wind Dir (deg)'})
new_df = wind_speed_df.merge(wind_dir_df, right_index=True, left_index=True)
new_df.drop(['variable_x', 'variable_y'], inplace=True, axis=1)
new_df['Time (min)'] = df['Time (min)'].repeat(3).reset_index(drop=True)

print new_df.head()
```

Comment: This all seems to work except for the last call adding back in the time ('min') column. It gives me a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. I'm also wondering if there's a way to easily do the same thing but using the index for cases where the column name might change

Comment: Yeah the index was [0, 0, 0] because of the repeat, had to add in a .drop.

Comment: I would think you could make a function and apply it to the df using .apply(lambda x: func(x))

Comment: Gotcha thanks. I ended up creating keys for each in the following way: keys=[c for c in df if c.startswith('Wind Dir')] and used endswith('Speed (m/s)') for the Speed column headers. Then used that in the value_vars. Thanks again!